# Confused by FPComplete

Tags: haskell

I haven't visited haskell.org for a while. When I did the other day, I discovered that a company called FPComplete have started offering a number of rather interesting Haskell services. However, there doesn't seem to be much documentation anywhere, and I'm a little bit confused...

If you go in through the "front door", you're *required* to create a user account before you can do anything. But sometimes you can click on example code and instantly start editing and running it - seemingly without requiring any kind of account. So is an account required or not? Is there some way I can just try stuff out without going to all the trouble of setting up an account?

Also, if I "start a project", is it public by default, or is it private? If I close my browser window, does it go away? Or does it stay in existence forever? If I don't actually want the project anymore, can I delete it somehow?

I'm also a little confused as to the difference between "FP Haskell Center" and "School of Haskell"...

Comment: The site evolved, so a few things were moved, I guess. You can log in using your Google+ account (so no need to create a new one). You can run examples, but after logging in you get much more interesting features (still for free). Projects created in your account are persistent, but I am not sure if they are private or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about navigating a particular website.

Comment: All projects (and tutorials) are private until published, no matter what license(s) the user has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

School of Haskell is a community-driven set of Haskell tutorials and articles with "live" code snippets embedded into them.

FP Haskell Center is a cloud IDE for Haskell with full-featured editor, git integration and so on.

After registration you can create both tutorials for School of Haskell and your own projects, which can be private. IDE projects are persistent, until you manually delete them.

Answer (score 5):

What makes you think you are required to create an account if you go through the front door? Yes, creating an account is the biggest thing on the page, but if you just ignore than and go into the alternatives in the lower half, you can create projects, etc, without going through the process of creating an account.

That will automatically create a temporary account. You can turn it into a permanent account by going through the registration process. That requires validating an email address. A google+ or Persona login will do, or you can go through the "here's my address - get email - click validation link" dance.